# Циклы в шаблонах ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Достаточно часто в шаблонах ansible требуется пройти по словарю (loop dictionary)

Представим, что у нас есть шаблон апачевского виртуалхоста и мы задаём набор для `php_value` и `php_admin_value`, что-то вроде:

```
  php_value:
    - { key: 'short_open_tag', value: 'on' }
  php_admin_value:
    - { key: 'max_input_vars', value: 1000 }
    - { key: 'upload_max_filesize', value: '1m' }
```

и где-то то в шаблоне:

```
{% for item in php_value %}
    php_value {{ item.key}} {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in php_admin_value %}
    php_admin_value {{ item.key}} {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Однако, хочется сделать запись в конфиг-файле более компактной, чтобы избавиться от излишних key value, чтобы не рябило в глазах при чтении.

Скажем, задавать данные в простом человекопонятном виде:

```
  php_value:
    short_open_tag: "on"
  php_value:
    pcre.recursion_limit: 1000
    upload_max_filesize: "1m"
```

Возможно ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Долго не знал, что искать, пока однажды не [натолкнулся](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756586/loop-dictionary-in-ansible-template) на простое и эффективное решение:

```
{% for item in php_value %}
    php_value {{ item }} {{ php_value[item] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Подходит для обхода одноуровнего key-value словаря типа:

```
  php_value:
    short_open_tag: "on"
  php_value:
    pcre.recursion_limit: 1000
    upload_max_filesize: "1m"
```

В принципе, всё работает корректно, даже точка внутри названия. Из известных особенностей: `short_open_tag: on` (именно без кавычек) преобразуется к виду `php_value short_open_tag: True` поэтому кавычки обязательны.